# Jsp page import in already imported page : path issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, import, jstl

I am developing a web application with `JavaEE` and I am using `JSTL` to render my views ; because there is a lot of views and big pages (Bootstrap styled content loaded by ajax), I decided to clearly separate my views into separate folders. I am also including partial views into biggest page template, in order to keep my code readable by an human. ;)

So, here comes the problem ; let's say my folder architecture looks like that :

- WEB-INF

  - application

    - view1.jsp
    - menus

      - menu1.jsp
      - menu2.jsp

Here is the "rules" :

- `menu1.jsp` is importing `menu2.jsp`
- `view1.jsp` is importing `menu1.jsp`

For now, everything is fine with this kind of code :

**view1.jsp**

```
<c:import url="menus/menu1.jsp" />
```

**menu1.jsp**

```
<c:import url="menus/menu2.jsp" />
```

I am forced to add `menus/` in my second import, because I found that the path is actually relative to the first-called page, so **view1.jsp**

Here is the problem : `menu1.jsp` is defining a structure for a menu, that could be loaded from the page's first loading (when I forwad my response to `view1.jsp`), or by a request made by ajax.

In that second case (with ajax), I directly forward my request to `menu1.jsp` without importing it from `view1.jsp` ; so the path of my import (for `menu2.jsp`) is not correct, 'because it should be `<c:import url="menu2.jsp" />` in that case.

I can put a conditionnal statement, and pass another attribute to my view that defines the actual page and change the import's path, but I'm not sure this would be the best solution. Is there a way to define paths relative to **root folder** (for example `WEB-INF`) in `c:import` directive ? For example, I would like to be able to do that :

**view1.jsp**

```
<c:import url="./application/menus/menu1.jsp" />
```

**menu1.jsp**

```
<c:import url="./application/menus/menu2.jsp" />
```

It would lead to longer URLs, but ensures the path validity ; [JSTL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/import.html) states that it can import `an absolute or relative URL`, but it seems to be used for *external* resources only.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate the problem that you explain above but I dont get the same results. I am importing the file view1.jsp from a JSP in the root of the application and must give it the full path of the view1.jsp file: `<c:import url="/WEB-INF/application/view1.jsp" />` likewise I have to do the same with the other import statements.

In any event, I think that you would be better to implement the MVC pattern with a front controller that can then take care of directing all requests for resources from the application.

I imagine it working like this:

The front controller is mapped to all paths "/*" and thus all request (regardless of path) will go via the controller. The controller servlet can retrieve the servlet path of the request and based on this direct the call to the appropriate resource. The advantages of using the MVC pattern are numerous, but in your specific case you will no longer need to worry about the location of files and just concentrate on the provision of the resources.

For example: an AJAX request for the menu JSP is received by the controller. The controller can determine that it is an AJAX request because it will retrieve the servlet path of the request and based on previously configured actions the request is redirected to the menu.

The AJAX request comes from the URL www.example.com/resources/ajax/menu the servlet path will be: resources/ajax/menu so you serve the menu1.jsp however a request from a page will be something like www.example.com/resources/menu and the servlet path will be: resources/menu so you serve view1.jsp.

Heres the code for the front controller:

```
    @WebServlet({"/*"})
    public class FrontController extends HttpServlet {

        public FrontController() {
            super();      
        }

        private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException{

            try {
                Action action = AbstractActionFactory.getInstance().getAction(request);
                String view = action.execute(request, response);
                request.getRequestDispatcher(view).forward(request, response);                     
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new ServletException("Executing action failed.", e);
            }       

        }

        /**
         * Delegate processing of GET/POST requests to the processRequest method.
         */ 
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
        }

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
        }
```

Here's the code for the actions. This is where you define how each resource is severed.

```
public class ActionFactory {

    private Map<String, Action> actions = new HashMap<String, Action>();
    private Action action;

    public ActionFactory() {            
        actions.put("GET/resources/ajax/menu/", new MenuAjaxAction());  
        actions.put("GET/resources/menu/",  new MenuAction());
    }

    public synchronized Action getAction(HttpServletRequest request) throws ActionFactoryException {        
        String path = request.getServletPath();     
        if (path != null || path.length() > 0){ 
            String actionKey = request.getMethod() + path;
            System.out.println(actionKey);
            action = actions.get(actionKey);
            if(action == null){
                action = actions.get("LoginRedirect");
            }
        } else {
            throw new ActionFactoryException();
        }

        return action;      
    }
}
```

You need the action interface:

```
public interface Action {       
    public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception;       
}
```

The abstract action factory:

```
public class AbstractActionFactory {        
    private final static ActionFactory instance = new ActionFactory();  
    private AbstractActionFactory() {}  
    public static ActionFactory getInstance() { 
        return instance;
    }
}
```

The action that serves the AJAX menu would look like this:

```
public class MenuAjaxAction implements Action {
    public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        return "/menuajax.jasp";
    }
}
```

The purpose of this action is to give you the chance to do any preprocessing of the menu before forwarding to it. For example you could query the database, retrieve some data and pass it to the menuajax.jsp view. If this is not necessary then just return the name of the JSP that import the menu file.

and the menuajax.jsp like so:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix ="c" %>
<c:import url="/WEB-INF/application/view1.jsp" />
```

This may seem overkill but the advantage of the MVC pattern is to separate the view from the model by using a controller.

You may wish to redirect to the menu.jsp directly from the action servlet (taking it out of the WEB-INF) file.

With this structure all requests for all pages/resources of your application go through the front controller. There is no need to refer directly to any resource on your server from your HTML pages. All will go through the front controller and the front controller will select the pages or whatever resource from the action factory class based on the URL (servlet path) of the request URL, making it very easy to swap around resources as all is controller in one central class file, rather than in 1000s of HTML/JSP files.

Comment: I have already implemented a MVC pattern with a front controller, but `import` seems to work differently, as it includes resources locally and so does not generate a new request (but in some way `forward` the current request). Anyway, for now it's working with a variable-based condition, but I'll try to use the full path with `/WEB-INF`